# Why merge replication wants to replicate view before replicating related table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, merge-replication

We have a publication and a subscriber running on 2 SQL 2016 servers. Now the error that we are receiving during subscription initialization is:

Error messages:

> The schema script 'vw_BlackList_961.sch' could not be propagated to
>   the subscriber. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number:
>   MSSQL_REPL-2147201001) Get help: http://help/MSSQL_REPL-2147201001
>   Unable to replicate a view or function because the referenced objects
>   or columns are not present on the Subscriber. (Source: MSSQL_REPL,
>   Error number: MSSQL_REPL20164) Get help: http://help/MSSQL_REPL20164
>   Invalid object name 'StaffBlacklistedSites'. (Source: MSSQLServer,
>   Error number: 208) Get help: http://help/208

Where is quite obvious that SQL server wants first to push VIEW instead first to push TABLE. How that is even possible? How to remedy this issue?

Thanks,
Dejan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this apply to your issue, but according MS-DOCS about this error:

[Error number: MSSQL_REPL-2147201001](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/mssql-repl-2147201001?view=sql-server-2016)

Maybe it is not about trying to replicate a VIEW before the TABLE, but another reasons.

Quoting from docs: (Bold is mine)

> **Explanation**
>
> COM object initialization failed for an XML Subscriber. Some reasons
>   why merge replication did not apply schema changes to the Subscriber
>   include the following:
>
> - A failure to create a directory to write the temporary snapshot files.
> - **A failure to enumerate schema articles**.
> - For SQL Server Compact Subscribers, a failure to reinitialize the
>     subscription.
> - If the object is message based, a failure to write to the message
>     file.

Perhaps for some reason it can't enumerate the schema properly, and then it is trying to replicate the view before the table.

You can have a look at errors log in this way:

> **User Action**
>
> Run SQL Server Profiler and examine replmerg.log for
>   failures. If you are using Web Synchronization, elevate the severity
>   of the websync log, rerun the scenario, and check for errors in the
>   websync.log file.

Comment: Thanks, yes it can be something else, in this last part I see that replmerg.log is mentioned, now do you know where I can find it and how to open it in profiler?

Comment: Have a look a [this](https://repltalk.com/2010/02/04/first-steps-in-troubleshooting-replication/) article.

Comment: Thank you, I will research that article too